# Slow build and install android. How build and install less minute

Tags: android, performance, build, kotlin, installation

I have many of big projects on android with many of library on kotlin. First build tahe 4 minutes.  When i try just replace some variable, before i can see result process build and install take around **1 minute.** I want to see result faster. In ios process build and install take around 15 sec.

**Instant run** dont work properly! First build take 4-6 minutes. And when i just replace some variable, process build and install take more  **1 minute.**  I use many of library and frameworks such as Rx, Dagger, Realm, Android Architecture Components.

I use **articles**, but that is **not enought**

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-speed-up-your-slow-gradle-builds-5d9a9545f91a

I try any methods what i can found in internet. I want to see result very fast. Just waiting build and install is taking a lot of my working time. If i reduce this step i can be more productive!

I want see result throw 15-20 sek like ios programm.
**What should i do? Is it normal build and install so slow on android?**

**My gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.caching=true
android.enableBuildCache=true 
android.enableD8=true
```

**My build.gradle**
https://github.com/Kadanza/Ling2/blob/master/app/build.gradle

**My PC.** 
Interl i5 3.2 GHz
16 RAM 
SSD